# Call SSIS package from external application deployed on AWS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ssis

We have to call SSIS package (Catalog) from an external application. Package is deployed on AWS. We can successfully execute package using window authentication but unable to execute it from an external application. We have created a procedure which basically trigger the package and application call the stored procedure to execute SSIS.
Our application is using SQL Server Auth. to connect AWS Sql Server which is an issue as SSIS can be executed with Window Authentication.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: *"Our application is using SQL Server Auth"* You cannot use SQL Authentication to start a package; if it's deployed to SSISDB (presumably it is) you get an explicit error telling you this.

Comment: I can't talk specifically for if this will work in an AWS environment, but if you "need" to use SQL Authentication then you will likely need to instead have to start an Agent Job which calls the Package instead. Of course, if you need to parametrise the call to the package, have it run synchronously, or have multiple instances of the package run at once, this isn't a viable option without a lot of extra (ugly) work. As such, ideally, you should set up your application to also use Windows Authentication; even if it is just for starting the package(s).

Comment: @Larnu : Yes, it is SSISDB. Suppose we use Agent Job in this scenario, can a proxy account help here. Instead of calling stored procedure, application trigger the Agent Job and job then trigger SSIS package. Any comment on this please? Thank you

Comment: *"Any comment on this please?"* No more than I already made.